# Simpson's rule for streams and even numbers of data point

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I was looking at numerical integration of data from a stream that I can't interpolate.  The trapezoidal rule worked more or less, but I wanted to improve on it, so I looked at Simpson's rule.  The deal with this is that normally, we'd apply it only intervals with a known midpoint, like this:

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx \approx \frac{b-a}{6} \left[ f(a) + 4f\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right) + f(b) \right]$$

However, given that I'm getting one data point at a time, and I want to have a running integral, I re-derived this for only the second half of the interval.  In this case, $a_1$ and $a_2$ are two previous $x$'s, and $b$ is the new $x$.  Here's what I got:

$$\int_{a_2}^b f(x) dx \approx \frac{b-a_2}{12} \left[ -f(a_1) + 8f(a_2) + 5f(b) \right]$$

I haven't tested it thoroughly to see how well this works.  But I just assume that I'm not the first to find this, and I was was wondering if anyone could point me to some prior work on this.

Comment: I'm not sure I have understood "I'm getting one data point at a time, and I want to have a running integral" properly, but why can't you wait and update the value of your integral every two "time slots"?

Comment: I'm simulating a machine, and I want an updated integral every interval.  But that's not really the point of my question.

Comment: I have difficulty in understanding the point of your question because the whole picture is not so clear to me...

Comment: @Albe:  Well, I derived this alternate form of Simpson's rule.  What I'd like to know is if it's useful (although I could do experiments) and who discovered this before me since surely I'm not the first to do this.